# Is support for recursive functions on the roadmap for Z3?

Tags: z3

The "define-fun-rec" syntax was added to the standard in June 28th. CVC4 has support for it. I was curious if support for solving constraints over recursive functions is currently underway? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

Note that you can use Z3 to reason about recursive functions by encoding their contracts as Horn clauses. Several Horn clause backends are available in Z3.
Also program verification systems, in particular Boogie, are very suitable to reason about recursive procedures. 
In lieu of syntactic support you can follow the shorthands suggested in 
http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-r2015-06-28.pdf, 
on page 58. You can also use other indirect encodings, of course, as in
Model Finding for Recursive Functions in SMT, http://smt2015.csl.sri.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/2015-Reynolds-Blanchette-Tinelli-Model-Finding-for-Recursive-Functions-in-SMT.pdf